Как установить нужный PyTorch для карточки Kepler 3.0 (GeForce GTX 670)?
Под Windows 10. На последних CUDA и CUDA 10.2 (последняя версия, поддерживающая 3.0) выдает следующую ошибку:
'''Found GPU0 GeForce GTX 670 which is of cuda capability 3.0.
PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
The minimum cuda capability supported by this library is 3.7.'''
Скачать PyTorch +cu102 какой либо версии не получается - не находится.
Хотя я скачал torch-1.9.1+cu102-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, но что с ним делать?
Вот здесь https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gpu-compatibility-error-nvidia-geforce-gt-710-with-cuda-capability-3-5-not-supported-by-pytorch/182318 говорят о том, что под нужную версию CUDA Capability 3.0 нужно PyTorch самому компилировать.
Скомпилировать самому, по этим шагам: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-from-source я точно не смогу :( не силен в этом.
Может кто уже делал такую сборку?
